# Is it possible to write an application in Java that schedules a meeting in Exchange?

Tags: exchange-server

I know it's possible to write an application in Java that retrieves Exchange meeting data, but is it possible to write one that actually schedules a meeting?

Comment: Which Exchange version are you using? 2000/2003 oder 2007/2010?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see the [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) specification

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  There is thorough documentation on the Microsoft website on how to do this using Visual Basic.  See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220595

Comment: This won't help at all - using an outlook control from VB cannot be (easily) implemented in a java program

Comment: You're right.  Apologies, I must have missed the "Java" specification, unless it was in an edit (and i see now that it was edited from "application" to "java application").

Comment: Edits to the question may have coincided with your answer - down vote removed (I edited your answer to allow me to do so - then rolled it back)